# how to use volley for multipart without encoded?

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-studio, android-fragments

I am using volley for image uploading from server. I tried with async task it works but I want to do with it using volley and I want solution for multipart using volley and without using encoded.

Answer (score 0):

you can upload to your server using multipartrequest

```
String url = "YOUR POST URL";
HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("your_extra_params", "value");
```

**Edit:** //String image_path = "your local image path";

**Update:**  //File part

```
Map<String, File> mFilePartData= new HashMap<>();
mFilePartData.put("file", new File(mFilePath));
mFilePartData.put("file", new File(mFilePath));



MultipartRequest multipartRequest =

        new MultipartRequest(url, params, mFilePartData, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Success Response: " + response.toString());

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                if (error.networkResponse != null) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error Response code: " +
                            error.networkResponse.statusCode);

            }
        });

requestQueue.add(multipartRequest);
```

Comment: Thanks for suggest me this but i want add multiple images..@SaravInfern

Comment: Thank you @SaravInfern but I want to send bitmap file without converting into byte array how can i send?

Comment: @ParthMistry the above code does not convert image into byte array, it is the path of the image file in you SD-Card

Comment: yes sir i know that but in my case i compress bitmap and add watermark in image and than i need to send image in to server using volley so in File its not accept bitmap

Comment: do you set the image(compressed and watermark added bitmap) in a image view??

Comment: yes and that image I want to send in multipart using volley @SaravInfern

Comment: `Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();`  get the image from the image view and make a file and try to upload it to server

Comment: Thank you @SaravInfern I will try it now.